# Adding Values to Custom Attribute using App Script

Tags: google-workspace

I have a requirement of adding Value to Custom attribute in G Suite for bulk users, I have added address and other field using App script but don't know how to add values to a custom attribute named "**Enhanced Desktop Security**" as shown in the image below.

Value to be added is using App Script is: "**un:Windows**"

[image]

Request your help with the Script.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this and came to know that 1st you have to identify the schemas of the custom attribute here : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list  Once you do that you can use the below script. Please make sure that you change the schema in the below script.

Mention "User Email ID",    "Value",    "Updation Status" in Cloumn A,B,C, respectively in sheet.

```
    function updateCustomE() {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(""); // Mention ID of the spreadsheet here.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(""); // Mention Name of the sheet here.
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var fileArray = [["Updation Status"]]


  for(i=1; i <values.length; i++)
  {

    var userKey = values[i][0]
    var customValue = values [i][1]


    try{
      var status = "Value not updated"
      var status = AdminDirectory.Users.update({
  "customSchemas": {
    "Enhanced_desktop_security" : {
      "Local_Windows_accounts" : [
        {
          "type": "custom",
          "value": customValue
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}, userKey);

      if (status != "Value not updated"){

        status = "Value updated Successfully"

      }

    }

    catch (e) {

      Logger.log(e.message)
      var status = e.message

    }

    fileArray.push([status])


  }

  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 3, fileArray.length, 1).setValues(fileArray)

}
```